# VBA script to copy adjacent cells if duplicate found

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2010

I know there are other questions like this but this is a specific issue with the code I am using. I've been trying to modify this VBA script to suit my purposes but so far I've been unsuccesful.
The code needs to cut and paste duplicate values into another column in the same row. eg if there are duplicates in A2,A3,A4 the contents of B3 and B4 need to move into C2 and D2.

```
Sub CheckDupl()
Dim x, i, nD As Integer
Dim c As String
Dim nLimit As Integer
Dim bFound As Boolean

nLimit = 6 '--> you can change this
nD = 2 '--> start row

For x = 1 To 3
  'Cells(x, 6) = "x"
  c = Cells(x, 1)
  bFound = False
  For n = x + 1 To nLimit
    If Not Cells(n, 6) = "x" Then
      If Cells(n, 1) = c Then
        If Not bFound Then
          bFound = True
          Cells(nD, 3) = Cells(x, 2)
          'Cells(nD, 4) = Cells(x, 3)
          'Cells(nD + 1, 3) = Cells(n, 2)
          Cells(nD, 4) = Cells(n, 2)
          'Cells(n, 6) = "x"
          nD = nD
        Else
          'Cells(nD, 5) = Cells(n, 2)
          Cells(nD, 5) = Cells(n, 2)
          'Cells(n, 6) = "x"
          nD = nD + 1
        End If

      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
End Sub
```

I have made it do what I need in principle but it won't move down the worksheet. [Here is a sample workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ieuts5i218xwk1b/DuplicateCopyAdjacent.xlsm?dl=0). How can I make it loop through the column and only paste the row I need?

[image]
So where row A has a duplicate, pear for example, A3 and A4 need to be put on the same row as the first occurrence of that term - so C2 and D2 in this case. The range is quite long about 1200 rows

Comment: For starters I would say rename your looping variables, because at least to me it adds to the confusion to have unnamed variables in a nested loop. Also for clarity, instead of saying 'Next', consider saying 'Next n' and then 'Next x', so reading it towards the bottom you know which iteration comes first. Also you should remove your comments there that just show other things you've tried in the past, both for our ease of reading and also for your own.

Comment: By "Duplicate", do you mean any duplicate in the column, or just if the cell above or below is the same? (does that make sense?)

Comment: I see the difference but that would only be important if the list wasn't sorted - in this case all the duplicates are grouped together. Would it therefore matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't really able to follow your code, and I am hesitant to download workbooks, but I have made this which you can tweak:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, sortRng As Range
Dim curString As String, nextString As String
Dim haveHeaders As Boolean

haveHeaders = False          ' Change this to TRUE if you have headers.

lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

If haveHeaders Then          'If you have headers, we'll start the ranges in Row 2
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Set sortRng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))
Else
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Set sortRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))
End If
' First, let's resort your data, to get all of the "Column A" values in order, which will group all duplicates together

With ActiveSheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .SetRange sortRng
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Now, let's move all "Column B" data for duplicates into Col. C

    ' We can check to see if the cell's value is a duplicate by simply counting how many times it appears in `rng`
    Dim isDuplicate As Integer, firstInstanceRow As Integer, lastInstanceRow As Integer

    If haveHeaders Then
        curString = Cells(2, 1).Value
    Else
        curString = Cells(1, 1).Value
    End If

    Dim dupRng As Range      'set the range for the duplicates
    Dim k   As Integer

    k = 0
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If i > lastRow Then Exit For
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        curString = Cells(i, 1).Value
        nextString = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        isDuplicate = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Cells(i, 1).Value)


        If isDuplicate > 1 Then
            firstInstanceRow = i
            Do Until Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Value <> nextString
                'Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Select
                lastInstanceRow = Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Row
                k = k + 1
            Loop

            Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 2)).Copy
            Cells(firstInstanceRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Range(Rows(firstInstanceRow + 1), Rows(lastInstanceRow)).EntireRow.Delete
            k = 0
            lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

How this works for me: I have data in Column A and B:

[image]

Note: I don't have headers.  I used Col. A to be the column that has the possible duplicate values.  First, it sorts by Col. A, to get all the numbers (or words, if alphabetical) in order.  This will have all duplicates together.  THen, it looks through each cell in column A, if there's more than 1 of that cell's value, move "B" info. to "C":

[image]

If you can post a screenshot, or just let me know where your data is, this can easily be tweaked to include more cells, other ranges, etc.

edit: quick way to loop through a column, just FYI:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
rng = ("A1:A100")

For Each cel In rng
    cel.Select
    ' Do whatever in the cell. After this is done, it'll go to the next one
    ' I chose to Select the cell because it helps me when debugging, to make sure I selected the right cells.  You can (should) comment that out when you know it works.
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: @ThomasSharp - I've updated the code.  Do as of now, it leaves the duplicate info in the cells.  Let me know if you want to delete those rows, remove the data, etc.

Comment: Nailed it. It could delete where the duplicate info was but this is not a problem for me.

Comment: Updated the code to delete those duplicate rows.  This should work for rows up to 32,767. (If you have more rows, just change the `Dim [whatever] as Integer`  to `Dim [whatever] as Long`.