# VBA script to copy adjacent cells on same row if duplicate found

Tags: vba, excel

I modified the code only at one point because it was what I needed but I need something extra and I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is the original code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881185/vba-script-to-copy-adjacent-cells-if-duplicate-found) post :

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, sortRng As Range
    Dim curString As String, nextString As String
    Dim haveHeaders As Boolean

    haveHeaders = False          ' Change this to TRUE if you have headers.

    lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    If haveHeaders Then          'If you have headers, we'll start the ranges in Row 2
        Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
        Set sortRng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))
    Else
        Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
        Set sortRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))
    End If
    ' First, let's resort your data, to get all of the "Column A" values in order, which will group all duplicates together

    With ActiveSheet
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange sortRng
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        ' Now, let's move all "Column B" data for duplicates into Col. C

        ' We can check to see if the cell's value is a duplicate by simply counting how many times it appears in `rng`
        Dim isDuplicate As Integer, firstInstanceRow As Integer, lastInstanceRow As Integer

        If haveHeaders Then
            curString = Cells(2, 1).Value
        Else
            curString = Cells(1, 1).Value
        End If

        Dim dupRng As Range      'set the range for the duplicates
        Dim k   As Integer

        k = 0
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If i > lastRow Then Exit For
            Cells(i, 1).Select
            curString = Cells(i, 1).Value
            nextString = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
            isDuplicate = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Cells(i, 1).Value)


            If isDuplicate > 1 Then
                firstInstanceRow = i
                Do While Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Value = nextString
                    'Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Select
                    lastInstanceRow = Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Row
                    k = k + 1
                Loop

                Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 3)).Copy
                Cells(firstInstanceRow, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Range(Rows(firstInstanceRow + 1), Rows(lastInstanceRow)).EntireRow.Delete
                k = 0
                lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            End If

        Next i
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

What I did is:

changed this:

```
Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 2)).Copy
Cells(firstInstanceRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

to

```
Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 3)).Copy
Cells(firstInstanceRow, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

What I have is:

Column A has duplicates.
Column B has unique value.
And column C has the qty for the unique values.
It works until the copy and paste part with the exception that it copies either column C under value from column B or the other way is that it copies each value from Column B with the qty from Column C but when it finishes, it deletes all the duplicates.

Example

```
Column A  Column B  column C
 322       sku322    qty 20
 322       322sku    qty 25
```

it outputs like

```
Column D   column E
 sku322     qty 20
 322sku     qty 25
```

And when it's finished, it delete the second row. This means that  i don't have the second unique value.

Or it outputs like:

```
Column D   Column E
 sku322     322sku
 qty 20     qty 25
```

And then it delete the last row and I don't have the qty anymore.
From my way of thinking if there is no way to paste on the same line, that would mean that after each find it should retake the loop and not copy/paste in bulk. But I tried multiple ways and can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a workaround, i don't know if it's the most feasable one but it works and for 10.000 rows it does it in 40 seconds to 1 minute max.

You need to create 3 modules and a function (i did not want to put the function in the on the modules.

Module 1

```
Sub Simplify()

Application.Run "Module9.RemovePart"
Application.Run "Module10.SameRowDuplicates"

End Sub
```

Module 2

```
Private Sub RemovePart()
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim fndRplc As Variant

With ActiveSheet
Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert 'Here i inserted a new column so i can duplicate the first column
Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy ' Copied the first column to the inserted one
Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' selected first column to remove the end of the sku
fndList = Array("FR", "DE", "ES") ' here you can just change to whatevery you want to remove
fndRplc = "" ' here is what it replaces it with


  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)


For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    Range("A1").EntireColumn.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=fndRplc, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
 Next i

Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Module 3

```
Private Sub SameRowDuplicates()
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim cel As Range, Rng As Range, sortRng As Range
Dim curString As String, nextString As String
Dim haveHeaders As Boolean

haveHeaders = True          ' Change this to TRUE if you have headers.

lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

If haveHeaders Then          'If you have headers, we'll start the ranges in Row 2
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Set sortRng = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
Else
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Set sortRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
End If
' First, let's resort your data, to get all of the "Column A" values in order, which will group all duplicates together

With ActiveSheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .SetRange sortRng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

' Now, let's move all "Column B" data for duplicates into Col. C

' We can check to see if the cell's value is a duplicate by simply counting how many times it appears in `rng`
Dim isDuplicate As Integer, firstInstanceRow As Integer, lastInstanceRow As Integer

If haveHeaders Then
    curString = Cells(2, 1).Value
Else
    curString = Cells(1, 1).Value
End If

Dim dupRng As Range      'set the range for the duplicates
Dim k   As Integer

k = 0
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If i > lastRow Then Exit For
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    curString = Cells(i, 1).Value
    nextString = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    isDuplicate = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cells(i, 1).Value)


    If isDuplicate > 1 Then
        firstInstanceRow = i
        Do Until Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Value <> nextString
            'Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Select
            lastInstanceRow = Cells(i, 1).Offset(k, 0).Row
            k = k + 1
        Loop

        Cells(firstInstanceRow, 5).Formula = "=Combine(" & Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 3)).Address(False, False) & ")" ' combine the results in one row so you have all the duplicates one after another
        Cells(firstInstanceRow, 5).Copy
        Cells(firstInstanceRow, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _ ' this is for converting comma delimited to columns
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Semicolon:=True ' here you should change your delimiter to what you are using
        Range(Rows(firstInstanceRow + 1), Rows(lastInstanceRow)).EntireRow.Delete
        k = 0
        lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    End If
Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Function 1

```
Function Combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = ";") As String
'Update 20130815
Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutStr As String
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Text <> ";" Then
        OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign
    End If
Next
Combine = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - 1)
End Function
```

So quick story:
Module 1 calls for the other modules, i did it this way to make things easier for the end-user so he doesn't see all the modules just needs to click one.
Module 2 removes any text from the selected cells
Module 3 finds the duplicates and puts them on one line delimited by what you select in the function module. And then deletes the duplicates row.
Function 1 takes the output of you selection and puts it on one row delimited.

That is all, thanks for everybody's help and i wish this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Hows this? Screenshot of the results:

Note: If you want the ENTIRE 'unique-sku' column instead of just the country code, change

```
country = Right(Cells(i, 2), 2)
```

to

```
country = Cells(i, 2).Value
```

[image]

**Code**:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Dim country As String, qty As Integer
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Headers
    dict("country") = "sum"

    ' Loop through all rows starting on row 2; per Column A
    For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        ' Country = last 2 letters of Column B
        country = Right(Cells(i, 2), 2)
        qty = CInt(Cells(i, 3).Value)

        ' If it already exists, add the new amount to the sum.
        If dict.Exists(country) Then
            qty = dict(country) + qty
        End If

        ' This will create it if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise, update.
        dict(country) = qty
    Next

        ' Here are some display options.
        ' Horizontal
        Range("F2").Resize(1, UBound(dict.Keys()) + 1).Value = dict.Keys()
        Range("F3").Resize(1, UBound(dict.Items()) + 1).Value = dict.Items()
        ' Vertical
        Range("F5").Resize(UBound(dict.Keys()) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys())
        Range("G5").Resize(UBound(dict.Items()) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items())

    Set dict = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Here you go. [link](http://i.imgur.com/4GJzYfe.jpg) as you can see, i have on the left the original and on the right the output of the vba, i cannot think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Based on that, I believe you simply need to change the above.

Comment: It does the same thing. It deletes the entire row but the problem is also that it does not put it on the same like as in the example. In the example i have the sku 1220 3 times as duplicate this means that the unique-sku and qty matching the unique-sku should be all on the same row.

Comment: We can continue down the path of debugging the script, but is this style/format of the resulting data required? Meaning a unique sku followed by paired columns of unique-sku and qty? Growing a list horizontally, duplicating column names really isn't a great practice. If you just need sums of qty, would a pivot table suffice? http://i.imgur.com/dUBXlHE.jpg

Comment: Column names i don't really need. The list i showed you is how we have it and it's more that you don't need to look through the list to see the qty for each country. This way you have it in a line and you can just focus on one product more easly. If it would have been only the total qty, then i would have done it, it was easier :)) but faith is not on my side that's why i need it like this. For easy management of the qty/country. The column name i just inserted to show what i mean.

Comment: Also, i don't really need it to be in the same sheet. I just need the values that are duplicate to be on the same row with the unique-sku and qty corresponding to it. In the example i put it in the same sheet because it seemed easier to show what i need then to have 2 different sheets. So my problem is that it does not put the unique-sku/qty of the duplicates on the same row.

Comment: Hey, based on what you said (don't need column names, just want easy view of qty/country), I wrote a quick script to plug the values based on country.

Comment: @Bogdan90i I'm pretty interested in this, considering I haven't had an excuse to play with VBA in a while. Did this solve for your need?

Comment: Hello, so i think i don't know exactly how to explain.

Comment: sorry took to long to edit. back to the answer. What i need is not the sum of unique sku or sku/country. I need some like: if the sku has duplicate then it copies the unique-sku and corresponding qty for unique-sku to the first sku line. this means i have 3 line with sku = 1234 and i have 3 unique-sku/qty like 1234FR - 20, 1234DE - 22, 1234UK - 12. Each of then is on one line. But after the vba runs, the will be on the same line, here is a more short example that i think will explain it better. [link](http://i.imgur.com/pSpwMnf.jpg)